# Windows batch string as delimiter for a string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file containing multiple lines. I need only this line :

```
 Table: DSMAIN_FRANF.DEF02_002_REF_B - Deleted row(s) count: 44
```

In fact, I need only the number at the end of the line. The length of the line is variable, also the number, but the substring " Deleted row(s) count:" will always be there.

How can I get only what comes after "Deleted row(s) count:" in a line?

Comment: are the quotes and the dot really part of the line?

Comment: You could use substring expansion like this, supposing the line is stored in variable `VAR`: `set "VAR=%VAR:*Deleted row(s) count: =%"`; this removes everything up to and including `Deleted row(s) count: ` (note that the search is done case-insensitively); if the surrounding quotes and the dot are part of the line string, you can remove the trailing `".` by `set "VAR=%VAR:".=%"` later; type `set /?` into a command prompt window for more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming, the syntax of the line is reliable (`___:_____ Deleted row(s) count: xx`)

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%i in ('find "Deleted row(s) count:" t.txt') do set /a count=%%i
echo %count%
```

(also assuming, there is only one of those lines; if several, this will give you the last one)